# Python script that adds blank video to audio (multiple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have several audio files(.aac) on a single folder. How do I convert all the audio files to separate videos on a different folder? Each video file should have a blank black screen from start to end.

Preferably: the date at which the video was taken should be the date at which the audio was recorded.